# Why isn't a managed property associated with a column returning when I query through the Search API?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, rest, search-api

I'm using SharePoint 2013 Enterprise on-premises.

So I've scoured the Search Schema up and down. I've perused & searched everyone of the Managed Properties and Crawled Properties. I simply cannot find one for a specific site column. The display name of the site column is 'Department'; however, when I click to edit the column, the url query string says Field=Division. I've searched managed & crawled properties for Division and found nothing. I've used the search api with the following URL:

```
http://<sharepoint 2013 server>/_api/search/query?querytext='"Tutorials"'&selectproperties='RankingWeightHigh,Department,People:Department,DiscussionCategory,ows_Category,Rank,Title,Path,FileExtension,ContentTypeId,IsDocument'
```

Department shows in the xml results that display, but it's Null. I'm wondering if this property doesn't refer to the Department field on the user profile..??

I've performed a full crawl, just in case, but the value for Department is still  null. The 2 managed properties we have associated with Department are People:Department and ows_Department. The Department field is queryable, searchable, retreiveable, and refinable (with 'Yes-Active' as the value).

Does anyone have any thoughts at all on what else I can try or what settings I should check?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Site Column in a list or library and does it have data? If so it should create a crawled property called `ows_Division`. It will also create another crawled and managed property automatically, but ignore that for now. For now check the SharePoint category for a crawled property called `ows_Division'.

Also, In your query it appears that you are trying to select a mix of crawled and managed properties, you cannot do that. Only managed properties that are Queryable can be used in the query and only Retrievable properties can be returned as selectedproperties.

Don't neglect testing permissions issues and ensuring that your documents have a published version, but I assume you have done that.

Comment: I believe it's a site column but am not certain. If I go to "Add Site Column", I see Department listed, but that may refer to a value on the User Profile. Still, I've located the managed 'Department' property and made it both queryable and searchable. I've also ensured the 'ows_Department' property is mapped to 'Department(text)', which I believe refers to the created column I made. Lastly, I am certain I have permission on the documents published.

Comment: If it is a site column it has nothing to do with the User Profile. They are totally separate. Above you said you were using Division, why are you using Department? I am really confused.

Comment: Because I don't see a managed property or crawled property named Division or containing the word 'Division' in it. And the column name itself is 'Department'. I do not know why, when I click onto the column to edit it, the url has 'Field=Divsion'.

Comment: It was initially created as "Division" then renamed. Are you certain it is a Site Column? Either way, there should be a crawled property called "ows_Division".

Comment: No, I'm not certain that it's a site column. Is there a way I can check? I am certain that no Division and no ows_Division crawled property was created.

Comment: Trace the field to its origin. If it's a site column that is where you will end up. Either way, you should troubleshoot why it's now creating the crawled property. Is there data in the column?